# Why doesn't Carbon work in the loop?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code:

```
foreach($tasks as &$task){
    dd(Carbon::parse($task->created_at)->diffForHumans());
}
```

It prints `"2 hours ago"`. All fine.

Now when I remove `dd()`, it throws error:

```
foreach($tasks as &$task){
    $task->created_at = Carbon::parse($task->created_at)->diffForHumans();
}

/*It throws:
    (1/1) InvalidArgumentException
     A two digit month could not be found
     Data missing
```

Does anybody how can I fix it?

Comment: Check to make sure `$task->created_at` isn't empty in one of the tasks. Throw `Log::info($task);` before your Carbon line, then check your laravel logs to see what it contains.

Answer (score 1):

To know `created_at` is an instance of Carbon so no need for the parse, also you can do this directly from the view if you want

```
{{$task->created_at->diffForHumans()}}
```

It fails because Laravel want to parse `2 hours ago` when you did `$task->created_at = Carbon::parse($task->created_at)->diffForHumans();` to put an instance of Carbon in the `created_at` field.

Comment: Altough it might be partially true, it does not explain why `dd(Carbon::parse($task->created_at)->diffForHumans());` works  and `$task->created_at = Carbon::parse($task->created_at)->diffForHumans();` does not.

Comment: @ThomasMoors i know because @Martin didn't ask why the first work and the second not he says `Does anybody how can I fix it?` and i explained why the exception is thrown, why dd(...) work is trivial